# Make ByteArray display in Binary

Tags: c#, .net

So I want to make a ByteArray to be displayed in Binary.

```
[HttpGet("GetCategoriesInByte")]
    public byte[] GetCategoriesInByte()
    {
        List<object> categoryList = new List<object>();
        var categories = Database.Categories
            .Where(eachCategoryEntity => eachCategoryEntity.DeletedAt == null).AsNoTracking();
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            categoryList.Add(new
            {
                CategoryId = category.CategoryId,
                CategoryName = category.CategoryName,
                CreatedAt = category.CreatedAt,
                UpdatedAt = category.UpdatedAt,
                DeletedAt = category.DeletedAt
            });
        }

        JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BsonWriter bsonWriter = new BsonWriter(memoryStream);
        jsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, categoryList);

        byte[] categoryListArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(categoryList.ToString());
        return categoryListArray;
    }//End of GetCategoriesInByte
```

The output now is:

> "U3lzdGVtLkNvbGxlY3Rpb25zLkdlbmVyaWMuTGlzdGAxW1N5c3RlbS5PYmplY3Rd"

I want it to be something like:

> 00100100.. and so forth

I want to send it over as a byte[] and display it as binary.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you see this output? and where do you want to display it?

Comment: No, "Binary String" is wrong.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I just want to see it in the console, it's not to be displayed, I just want it displayed in Binary. Right now I'm using PostMan and the API to get the output shown to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hey, thanks for the critique, may I know the correct term?

Comment: @ShawnL. - It's a `List<object>` or "List of Objects", or, more specifically, in this case, a "List of Anonymous Objects".

Comment: @Enigmativity - Thank you for the enlightenment.

Comment: @ShawnL. - My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            memoryStream.Position = 0; // reset memory string to beginning after write all data
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
            byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes((int)memoryStream.Length);
            string hex = string.Join("", data.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't want to return a string.

Comment: Last line to convert to string isn't necessary.  Just included to get the hex values similar to your request.